# Android JavaMail send mail with Exchange server

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail, exchange-server

I'm trying to send an email using my company server but something doesn't work.

```
private Properties _setProperties() {


    _port = 443;
    _sport = 443;
    Properties props = (Properties) System.getProperties().clone();

    props.put("mail.smtps.host", _host);
    props.put("mails.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");

    props.put("mail.smtps.port", _port);
    props.put("mail.smtps.ssl.port", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtps.ssl.socketFactory.port", _sport);
    props.put("mail.smtps.ssl.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtps.ssl.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    return props;
}

public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

    _user = "email";
    _pass = "pass";

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);
    session.setDebug(true);

    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_user));
    msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, "mailTO");
    msg.setSubject("SUBJECT");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    msg.setText("TEXT");

    // send email
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
    transport.connect();
    transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();

    return true;

}
```

The debug shows the following:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.5

DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle]

DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication

DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true

DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "companyServer", port 443, isSSL true
```

Keeps trying to connect and doesn't give any answer. When I set the mail.smtps.writetimeout it returns me java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

Any idea? :S

Comment: Fix these [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) and make sure you're using the official [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android).  Then follow these [connection debugging tips](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep noted that all Outlook clients use either MAPI or MAPI-over-http (MAC used EWS). Therefore most Exchange administrators might not have allowed users to use SMTP and therefore it might not be working as you expect.

Did you checked with your MS Exchange administrator if you can use SMTP via that way?

Comment: You're right, I checked with my Exchange administrator and I can not use SMTP, I have to use EWS. I tried with [EWS Andorid API] (github.com/alipov/ews-android-api) but it give an execution error because doesn't found some classes, like apache that has been deleted

Comment: I´m not an android developer but an good starting point might be ["How to: Send email messages by using EWS in Exchange"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn600292(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Comment: Thanks but the date of last modified is on March 09, 2015 and now I don't have the libraries to do it